# How to add a twig link in the url of an easyadmin menu?

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

How to add a twig link in the url of an easyadmin menu?

**easy_admin.yml :**

```
design:  
      menu:
          - ...
          - { label: 'Language', icon: language, children: [{ label: FR,  url: 'easy_admin/Language/fr.html.twig'}, { label: EN, url: 'easy_admin/Language/en.html.twig' }] } //Doesn't work
```

**fr.html.twig :**

```
{{ path('setlocale', {'language': 'fr'}) }}
```

Comment: Maybe this article from the official doc can help you: [how to link to Symfony routes in EasyAdmin menus](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/menu-configuration.html#symfony-routes)